# Question about Lyapunov stability for a nonlinear system with inputs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory

I am studying Lyapunov stability for systems of the type:

$\dot{x}=f(x)$

and I think I have well understood the theory.

But, suppose now I have a system with an input, so of the type:

$\dot{x}=f(x)+g(x)u$

**Can I still use the Lyapunov analysis for analizing the stability of this system?**

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to study. By default, the Lyapunov analysis is about the behavior of autonomous systems, e.g., when the loop is closed with $u(t) = \kappa(x(t))$. Moreover, the most common definitions of stability also consider the behavior of trajectories of autonomous systems in a neighborhood of an equilibrium. Thus, yes, you can use the Lyapunov analysis, but you should define what exactly do you study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but there are extensions that allow you to do so.

You can look up *input to state stability* for example. But you will need some assumptions for $u$, for example that the input is bounded.

For example, the system

$$
\dot{x} = -x^3 + xu
$$

is input to state stable if $|u| < C$ for any finite positive $C$ because as $x$ gets large the stabilizing $-x^3$ "beats" the $xu$.

But the system

$$
\dot{x} = -x^3 + x^3u
$$

is not input to state stable for any bounded input, because with the input $u = 2$ you get

$$
\dot{x} = x^3
$$

which is unstable.

This is of course not very rigorous but there exists a rigorous theory and a lot of literature for this topic. However it gets quickly much more complicated if you have more complicated systems.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If possible, could you tell me some source where this is explained clearly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @J.D. Take a look at the paper "Input to State Stability: Basic Concepts and Results" by Sontag et al.